# MVC - Create a database table using displayed table in html

Tags: html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to save a html table which is created from excel reader in my MVC project.
This is code of uploading excel and display it in HTML table in the browser:

Upload function:

```
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // ExcelDataReader works with the binary Excel file, so it needs a FileStream
                // to get started. This is how we avoid dependencies on ACE or Interop:
                Stream stream = upload.InputStream;

                // We return the interface, so that
                IExcelDataReader reader = null;


                if (upload.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
                }
                else if (upload.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "This file format is not supported");
                    return View();
                }

                reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

                DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
                reader.Close();

                return View(result.Tables[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Upload Your file");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And this is my View Code:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data;

<h2>Upload File</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "ImportData", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" id="dataFile" name="upload" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>

    if (Model != null)
    {
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                        {
                            <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
}
```

### After using the previous code the html will browsed in the view like the below image :

### [image]

Finally, I need to save this HTML table as a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE ExcelSheet_name(
   ID varchar(50),
   FirstName varchar(50),
   LastName varchar(50),
   .....
   XColumn varchar(50));
```

the table name depending on the excel sheet name and the column will be depending on the displayed column in the HTML table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this within Entity Framework with c# code only, but a SQL solution can be generated.

In your controller, insert a function call after the reader is closed to create the table.

```
reader.Close();

CreateTableFromExcelData( upload.FileName, result.Tables[0] );

return View(result.Tables[0]);
...
```

Add new function

```
public void CreateTableFromExcelData( string fileName, DataTable table )
{
    string sql = "create table " + fileName + "( ";
    List<string> cols = new List<string>();
    foreach ( DataColumn col in table.Columns )
    {
        cols.add( "[" + col.ColumnName + "] varchar(50)" );
    }
    sql += String.Join(",", cols ) + ")"; 
    // Command to execute sql here like
    // _db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( sql );
    // where _db is your database context
}
```